Ошибка: Cannot find module при подключении vue-multiselect.min.css

правильно импортировал
версии не конфликтуют
все пробовал не могу решить

Vue 2, vue-multiselect 15, weebpack 4, laravel mix 5,
admin.js:131099 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'vue-multiselect/dist/vue-        
multiselect.min.css'
at webpackMissingModule (admin.js:131099:50)
at admin.js:131099:169
at admin.js:131149:3
at admin.js:131151:12


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Видимо не правильно импортировали, т.к. стили компонента он не может найти. Покажите код подключения компонента
